# Let $a,b$ be two elements of a group $G$ then which one is correct choice?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $a,b$ be two elements of a group $G$ such that $a^7 = b^7$ and $a^3 = b^3$ implies $a = b$, then which of the following is possible ?

(i) $a,b \in\Bbb Z_{6}$,

(ii) $a,b \in\Bbb Z_{3}$,

(iii) $a,b \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$,

(iv) $a,b \in \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$.

Now, here all groups are abelian so,

$(ab^{-1})^7 = e$ and $(ab^{-1})^3 = e$

So, we get $o(ab^{-1})\mid 3$ and $o(ab^{-1})\mid 7$, this implies $o(ab^{-1}) = 1$

Hence $a = b$

Since , I have only utilised the property that given Group $G$ is abelian, this should be true for finite as well as infinite groups.

So, all  options should be correct

Is my answer and reasoning correct ? Can someone please verify ?

Thank you.

Comment: As formulated, every group is possible. For example, let $a=b=e$ be the two elements.

Comment: I don't think you even need abelian: $a = a^7 a^{-3} a^{-3} = b^7 b^{-3} b^{-3} = b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a^3=b^3$ then $a^6=b^6$. Now multiply both sides of $a^7=b^7$ by $a^{-6}$ and $b^{-6}$ respectively.